# How to pass configuration argument on jboss

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I added db2 driver, edited `module.xml` in `JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/ibm/main`.
In this folder, I have

- db2jcc4.jar
- db2jcc_lecense_cu.jar
- db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar
- module.xml

After having these, I tried to launch JBoss console on Powershell

```
.\standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full-ha.xml -Dcom.sun.CORBA.ORBDynamicStubFactoryFactoryClass=com.sun.corba.se.impl.presentation.rmi.StubFactoryFactoryStaticImpl
```

which I tried to handle ORB exception(related to this https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6497156)
But my jboss container is not launched. I checked the log file,

```
2019-09-17 296 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0239: Aborting with exit code
```

and error display on Powershell

```
WFLYSRV0073: Invalid option '.sun.CORBA.ORBDynamicStubFactoryFactoryClass=com.sun.corba.se.impl.presentation.rmi.StubFactoryFactoryStaticImpl'
```

It works on command prompts though. I am wondering it is correct way to pass argument like this. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
I am using Java8, JBoss7.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Powershell has issues with `-D`. Try this instead, notice the `"` around `-D`

```
.\standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full-ha.xml "-Dcom.sun.CORBA.ORBDynamicStubFactoryFactoryClass=com.sun.corba.se.impl.presentation.rmi.StubFactoryFactoryStaticImpl"
```